# What are the uses of the exec command in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, unix, exec

Can anyone explain what are the uses of the exec command in shell scripting with simple examples?

Comment: The links to linux.about.com are not helpful. They don't make it remotely clear how executing a command or pipeline of commands using 'exec' differs from just executing them normally. Hence the OP's question "what is the use of exec"?

Comment: [The Uses of the Exec Command in Shell Script](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/exec-command-in-shell-script)
Is this link helpful?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

The `exec` built-in command mirrors functions in the kernel, there are a family of them based on `execve`, which is usually called from C.

`exec` replaces the current program in the current process, without `fork`ing a new process.  It is not something you would use in every script you write, but it comes in handy on occasion.  Here are some scenarios I have used it;

1. We want the user to run a specific application program without access to the shell.  We could change the sign-in program in /etc/passwd, but maybe we want environment setting to be used from start-up files.  So, in (say) `.profile`, the last statement says something like:

   ```
    exec appln-program
   ```

   so now there is no shell to go back to.  Even if `appln-program` crashes, the end-user cannot get to a shell, because it is not there - the `exec` replaced it.
2. We want to use a different shell to the one in /etc/passwd.   Stupid as it may seem, some sites do not allow users to alter their sign-in shell.  One site I know had everyone start with `csh`, and everyone just put into their `.login` (csh start-up file) a call to `ksh`.  While that worked, it left a stray `csh` process running, and the logout was two stage which could get confusing. So we changed it to `exec ksh` which just replaced the c-shell program with the korn shell, and made everything simpler (there are other issues with this, such as the fact that the `ksh` is not a login-shell).
3. Just to save processes.  If we call `prog1 -> prog2 -> prog3 -> prog4` etc. and never go back, then make each call an exec.  It saves resources (not much, admittedly, unless repeated) and makes shutdown simplier.

You have obviously seen `exec` used somewhere, perhaps if you showed the code that's bugging you we could justify its use.

**Edit**:  I realised that my answer above is incomplete.  There are **two** uses of `exec` in shells like `ksh` and `bash` - used for opening file descriptors.  Here are some examples:

```
exec 3< thisfile          # open "thisfile" for reading on file descriptor 3
exec 4> thatfile          # open "thatfile" for writing on file descriptor 4
exec 8<> tother           # open "tother" for reading and writing on fd 8
exec 6>> other            # open "other" for appending on file descriptor 6
exec 5<&0                 # copy read file descriptor 0 onto file descriptor 5
exec 7>&4                 # copy write file descriptor 4 onto 7
exec 3<&-                 # close the read file descriptor 3
exec 6>&-                 # close the write file descriptor 6
```

Note that spacing is very important here.  If you place a space between the fd number and the redirection symbol then `exec` reverts to the original meaning:

```
  exec 3 < thisfile       # oops, overwrite the current program with command "3"
```

There are several ways you can use these, on ksh use `read -u` or `print -u`, on `bash`, for example:

```
read <&3
echo stuff >&4
```

Comment: there's also another use I found quite handy and worth mentioning here because it relates to python web applications and seems something in between your (awesome) answers 2 and 3. I usually run wsgi web apps (say django or flask) through [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/running.html) calling a [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) app: the latter notoriously requiring quite a few environment variables, it's way easier and more maintainable running gunicorn from a shell script that sets everything up and eventually `exec gunicorn` giving the correct pid back to supervisor.

Comment: The docs do say that `exec` can be used for redirection:  

> If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell, and the return status is 0.  If there is a redirection error, the return status is 1.  

But _how_ does `exec` actually work to change a file descriptor?  Why is this particular command chosen for this task?

(Markdown is failing right now?)

Comment: @Ray:  best I can do it: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/exec.html  .  If you need to know how then look at the shell source code.

Comment: Another use: Redirect all a script's output to a  logfile `exec >.\logfilename.log 2>&1`

Comment: Yes, it means execute the command specified on the command-line.  Look-up the `@` variable in `man bash`.  The `exec` replaces the current program with a new one, again, look-up `exec` in the man pages.

Comment: Related follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603122/understanding-exec-in-bash

Comment: Could you please explain `exec &> /var/log/userdata.log`, when followed by other commands such as yum install? It seems to me that it causes commands to be outputted to log file instead of being executed

Comment: @Carmageddon:  `&>` is a `bash` extension (see `man bash`) and your example is equivalent to `exec >/var/log/userdata.log 2>&1`.  In other words it redirects stdout and stderr to that file.  Commands that follow will inherit those redirections unless they are reset, but they will be executed.

Answer (score 67):

Just to augment the accepted answer with a brief newbie-friendly short answer, you probably don't need `exec`.

If you're still here, the following discussion should hopefully reveal why.  When you run, say,

```
sh -c 'command'
```

you run a `sh` instance, then start `command` as a child of that `sh` instance.  When `command` finishes, the `sh` instance also finishes.

```
sh -c 'exec command'
```

runs a `sh` instance, then *replaces* that `sh` instance with the `command` binary, and runs that instead.

Of course, both of these are useless in this limited context; you simply want

```
command
```

There are some fringe situations where you want the shell to read its configuration file or somehow otherwise set up the environment as a preparation for running `command`.  This is pretty much the sole situation where `exec command` is useful.

```
#!/bin/sh
ENVIRONMENT=$(some complex task)
exec command
```

This does some stuff to prepare the environment so that it contains what is needed.  Once that's done, the `sh` instance is no longer necessary, and so it's a (minor) optimization to simply replace the `sh` instance with the `command` process, rather than have `sh` run it as a child process and wait for it, then exit as soon as it finishes.

Similarly, if you want to free up as much resources as possible for a heavyish command at the end of a shell script, you might want to `exec` that command as an optimization.

If something forces you to run `sh` but you really wanted to run something else, `exec something else` is of course a workaround to replace the undesired `sh` instance (like for example if you really wanted to run your own spiffy `gosh` instead of `sh` but yours isn't listed in `/etc/shells` so you can't specify it as your login shell).

The second use of `exec` to manipulate file descriptors is a separate topic.  The accepted answer covers that nicely; to keep this self-contained, I'll just defer to the manual for anything where `exec` is followed by a redirect instead of a command name.

Comment: Thanks tripleee for the excellent reply and vote up. Wondering for the two ways I could execute -- (1) `bash -c "<command>"`, (2) `bash -c "exec <command>"`, then after the execution I check the return status by using `$?`, wondering if there are any differences? Are in both cases `$?` tracking if the `<command>` is successful? Or tracking if shell itself is ok?

Comment: Resisting the temptation to call your own spiffy shell `bush`.  Of course, this applies to `bash` or generally any popular Unix shell as well; though as @anishsane [notes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37851568/874188), Bash secretly optimizes `bash -c 'command'` by actually doing `exec command`.

Comment: The exit code of the shell is generally the exit code of the last command it executed.  Of course, if the shell fails to run, or to execute the command, the shell's exit status will reflect that with a suitable error code.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, vote up for both posts, and wondering if `exec` understand bash conditional execution like `||` and `&&`? Thanks.

Comment: Following up with tangential questions should be avoided.  Thanks.  A little experimentation would reveal what happens when you try `bash -c 'exec nonesvch || echo still here'` (hint: it doesn't `echo` and the exit code is 127).

Comment: There is no point in `sh -c command` in my book; you could just as well write `command` and it would have essentially the same effect, with one less process.  So, the first section of this answer really isn't helpful — as you go on to admit. You can use `exec` to terminate the script and replace it with whatever command you execute; this cuts down the number of processes and gets the shell out of the loop when reporting the exit status.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am deliberately documenting an antipattern which I see in newbie questions.  This one was prompted by [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580978/difference-between-running-a-bash-command-with-and-without-exec) but I have seen it before, so I wanted to cover that specifically.

Comment: Then you need to clarify the first paragraph — a lot.  That isn't how it reads at the moment.  It currently says "you don't need `exec command` because you can use `sh -c command` instead".  If that isn't what you want it to say, you have to revise the language to make it 100% explicit.  Lemme know when you've revised it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Minor wording tweak; is this sufficient, do you think?  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Better, but ... well, you might want to use `exec command` when the command is the last statement in the script — instead of just `command`.  I think I'd prefer a bigger rewrite.

Comment: Thanks - I added another brief paragraph about this optimization. It's not really clear to me if you have other objections, or if you would just like to explain things from a different angle.

Comment: Another useful use of `exec` is to patch the arguments. Let me give an example. libvirt/xapi calls qemu with some standard arguments. If I want to patch some arguments on the fly, I move `/path/to/qemu` to `/path/to/qemu.bin`; create a shell script at `/path/to/qemu` with contents: `a=("$@"); add_remove_modify_arguments_in_array_a; exec /path/to/qemu.bin "${a[@]}"`