# Redirecting standard input in Bash implies that Bash exits

Tags: bash

When I do,

```
$ exec 6<&0 0</tmp/lines.txt
```

bash exits. Why?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: @mbratch: There are two uses for exec, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-is-the-use-of-exec-command-in-the-shell-scripting/18351547#18351547

Comment: The next question is, what are you *trying* to accomplish? I suspect you want to redirect standard input for all the commands that follow, not the current shell itself.

Comment: @cdarke thanks a bunch. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

That makes bash read commands from `/tmp/lines.txt` redirecting its input in the process. There would no longer be any input to process after all those commands in the file so the shell just exits after it, just like executing a shell script.

If you want to not let bash exit after the commands in /tmp/lines.txt were processed, make sure that you could put back its input like:

```
exec 6<&0 < <(cat /tmp/lines.txt; echo; echo "exec <&6";)
```

Which send both inputs of `/tmp/lines.txt` as commands and also `exec <&6` that would put back input from `&6` encapsulated by process substition.

And a cleaner approach:

```
exec 6<&0 < <(cat /tmp/lines.txt; echo; echo "exec <&- <&6 6<&-";)
```

Or simply:

```
exec 6<&0 < <(cat /tmp/lines.txt; echo; echo "exec <&6-)
```

Comment: +1 for the process substitution trick. Perhaps make it `exec <&6-` to tidy up fd 6?

Comment: @je4d Made an update. I actually tried to avoid it at first to make it a bit clear for the user.

Comment: You don't need to close fd 6 separately/explicitly like that, `<&6-` moves the fd in one step (see bash(1)/"Moving File Descriptors")