# Redirecting standard input in Bash implies that Bash executes a default action?

Tags: bash

Yesterday I asked also this question. Thanks for all the answers. But I still don't get it.

I did

```
$ exec 6<&0 0</tmp/lines.txt
```

I thought: My standard input is redirected now. But the lines in the file are also executed! So is there a default action when you only do this? This is my question.

Let's say

```
$ cat /tmp/lines.txt 
read i j
read i j
echo "i:$i,j:$j">/tmp/res.txt
```

I do the exec, and after that I do

```
$ cat /tmp/res.txt 
i:read,j:i j
```

But when I do

```
$ exec 6<&0 0</tmp/lines.txt;exec 0<&6 6<&-
```

nothing is read or executed. I can read the lines but now I have to give the action myself,

```
$ exec 6<&0 0</tmp/lines.txt ;while read i j;do echo "i:$i,j:$j";done
```

I see in my terminal,

```
i:read,j:i j
i:read,j:i j
i:echo,j:"i:$i,j:$j">/tmp/res.txt
```

Thanks again, I hope it is not too long,

Eric J.

Comment: In interactive mode, bash reads commands from standard input.  Is that what you mean by a default action?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
exec 6<&0 0</tmp/lines.txt; exec 0<&6 6<&-
```

Turns out that bash still executes what remains in the command specified or script before it reads input for commands again that's why your file `/tmp/lines.txt` is not read since `exec 0<&6 6<&-` is run before it.

Please refer back to the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18700930/445221) if you want to execute commands in `/tmp/lines.txt` before `exec 0<&6-` is executed.

Also it might have not been obvious but you could use `.` or `source` to achieve same output:

```
. /tmp/lines.txt
source /tmp/lines.txt
```