# what is the difference between ls and "exec ls" in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

When I try to execute the `exec ls`,  my putty session is getting closed. What is the difference between `ls` and `exec ls` ?

Why do we need the `exec` command, and what are the uses of this command ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18351547/1983854

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of exec command in the shell scripting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-is-the-use-of-exec-command-in-the-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 3):

`exec` replaces the current process (the shell) with the new process. If you call a program without `exec`, the shell will fork a new process and then replace the new process with the program.

Answer (score 3):

`exec` is a shell built-in command.
In the manpage it says

> If exec is specified with command, it shall replace the shell with command without creating a new process.

So when you execute `exec ls` in the shell, your shell will be replaced with the `ls` process; when this process ends, the shell exits. Compared with `source` or `.`, this could be useful in shell scripts.