# upstart: echo in script

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

in my upstart script (Ubuntu 12.04.2) I have the following:

```
exec touch /tmp/000
exec echo "ds1307 0x68" >  /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-3/device/new_device
exec touch /tmp/111
exec hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 --hctosys  
exec touch /tmp/222
```

The problem is that /tmp/000 is there but none of the other files in /tmp. So it seems after the echo the script stops.

How to rewrite the line with the echo so the script does not stop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command exec replaces the current process with, in your case, the 
`touch` command in line 1. Afterwards there is no shell any more to return.

[Answer: explaining the exec command.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-is-the-use-of-exec-command-in-the-shell-scripting)

Try your script without the exec's.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all the exec's with the following:

```
script
  touch /tmp/000
  echo "ds1307 0x68" >  /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-3/device/new_device
  touch /tmp/111
  hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 --hctosys  
  touch /tmp/222
end script
```