# Bash file descriptor 3 and while read line

Tags: bash, while-loop, file-descriptor

I have been looking and couldnt find clear clues to verify what I am deducing from a script given to me.

so file.txt is an opened file (by the file descriptor 3) and is constantly adding a new line by a script that records timestamp. Does the following piece make into the while loop each time a new line is added to the file?

```
exec 3 < /path/file.txt
while read <&3
  command
  command..
done
```

So as long as I dont close the file descriptor, a new line added to my file.txt will always activate the while loop, right?

Please help me clear this up. Thanks

Comment: you might be interested in a detailed explanation of `exec` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 8):

To read from file descriptor 3, use `read -u 3` (see [Bash builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)).  Don't forget to specify the variable name into which the value should be read.

Once `read` detects EOF, it stays at EOF; it won't spot additions to the file after that.  So, if the code adding lines to the file is slower than the code in this script, you will reach and end point and the loop will terminate.  If you don't want that, consider using `tail -f /path/file.txt`, and maybe [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) too:

```
while read -u 3 line
do
    command1
    command2
done 3< <(tail -f /path/file.txt)
```

Or, if you want to do the `exec`:

```
exec 3< <(tail -f /path/file.txt)

while read -u 3 line
do
    command1
    command2
done
```

Note that the `tail -f` loops will never finish until you interrupt the script in some way.

Comment: `read -u 3` allows redirection from a file descriptor on a `per code-block basis` without requiring a manual open of the descriptor with `exec`. `while read <&3` is fine where the descriptor is opened with `exec` and will require a close with `exec 3>&-`.

Answer (score 3):

> So as long as I dont close the file descriptor, a new line added to my
>   file.txt will always activate the while loop, right?

**Answer: wrong.**

Redirecting `exec 3 < /path/file.txt` gives you the ability to **read** from `/path/file.txt` using the file descriptor, but does **nothing** to allow any type of **triggering** from `/path/file.txt` to your code. Think about it this way. **If there is a new line** in `/path/file.txt`, you can **read** it, but the redirection provides **no way of knowing** whether or not a new line has been added to the file for your code to respond to. It's still up to your code to check.