# Interrupt sleep in bash with a signal trap

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to catch the `SIGUSR1` signal in a bash script that is sleeping via the `sleep` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Caught SIGUSR1"' SIGUSR1

echo "Sleeping.  Pid=$$"
while :
do
    sleep 10
    echo "Sleep over"
done
```

The signal trap works, but the message being echoed is not displayed until the `sleep 10` has finished.
It appears the bash signal handling waits until the current command finished before processing the signal.

Is there a way to have it interrupt the running `sleep` command as soon as it gets the signal, the same way a C program would interrupt the libc `sleep()` function?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Caught SIGUSR1"' SIGUSR1

echo "Sleeping.  Pid=$$"
while :
do
   sleep 10 &
   wait $!
   echo "Sleep over"
done
```

Comment: Some [relevant info](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#When_is_the_signal_handled.3F)

Comment: Replace 10 by infinity such as "sleep infinity &"

Comment: @iruvar your link is worth it's weight in gold. not being able to interrupt a sleep from a different process *very very very counter-intuitive*.

Comment: according to that link, when bash is interrupted, `sleep 10` is not automatically killed, should add it to the trap ?

Answer (score 17):

Just a point about the `wait` after the `sleep` because I've just made this error in my script:

> You should use **`wait $!`** instead of `wait` if, inside your script, you already launched other processes in background

For example, the `wait` inside the next snippet of code will *wait* for the termination of both `process_1` and `sleep 10`:

```
process_1 &
  ...
sleep 10 &
wait
```

If you use, instead of `wait`, `wait $!` your script will wait only for `sleep 10`, because `$!` means *PID of last backgrounded process*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed my answer as suggested by you.

Answer (score 6):

Remark that

```
sleep infinity &
wait
```

puts the sleep in background, and stops the wait with the signal. This leaves an infinite sleep behind on every signal !

Replace the sleep and wait with

```
read
```

and you will be fine.

Comment: I don't think it does leave a background process hanging, at least not on MacOS 10.12.

Comment: `read` doesn't wait forever. User presses enter -> immediate return. Stdin is connected to `/dev/null` -> immediate return.

Comment: `read` trick is interesting thanks. If you want to be sure to never read anything you may use: `read -u 2` in [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352868/bash-file-descriptor-3-and-while-read-line) which instructs `read` to get its input from a file description number 2 (which is `stderr` which obviously will never any input).