# signal trap induces next command execution in bash

Tags: bash, signals, wait, sleep

Following [Interrupt sleep in bash with a signal trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694818/interrupt-sleep-in-bash-with-a-signal-trap), I run the code :

```
trap "echo 'Doing something'" SIGUSR1

echo "$$" > .daemon.pid
while true
do
    echo "in loop"
    sleep 60 &
    wait $!
done
```

The signal trap works, but daemon then goes to the next iteration of the infinite while loop, even if the sleep has not ended.

I then modify the while loop inner code as following (addition of a second wait command) :

```
while true
do
    echo "in loop"
    sleep 60 &
    wait $!
    wait $!
done
```

In that case I am able to send 2 trap commands before the daemon goes to the next iteration, still even if the sleep as not ended.

Is it possible to enforce that the daemon resume the sleep after trap such that it does not go to next iteration before the end of the sleep execution, regardless of the number of signals sent ?

**EDIT**: Ugly answer

I have found an ugly answer. I am still awaiting a better answer that might less ugly :) for the charm of code...

```
while :
do
    echo "in loop"
    sleep 60 &
    while ! wait $!
    do
        continue
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to enforce that the daemon resume the sleep after trap …

Actually, the `sleep` can't be *resumed*, since it is not even interrupted - only `wait` is.

> I am still awaiting a better answer that might less ugly …

As uglyness is a matter of taste, less ugly than

```
    while ! wait $!
    do
        continue
    done
```

one *might* find

```
    until wait $!; do :; done
```

or just

```
    until wait; do :; done
```

(if there's no other currently active child process).