# Bash script catch signal but wait afterwards for processes to terminate

Tags: linux, bash, signals

currently I'm writing a bash script like this:

```sh
foo(){
  while true
  do
    sleep 10
  done
}

bar(){
  while true
  do
    sleep 20
  done
}

foo &
bar &

wait
```

(I know there is no point in such a script, it's just about the structure)

Now I want to add signal handling with `trap -- <doSomething> RTMIN+1`. This works at first. When the script receives the rtmin+1 signal it does doSomething but afterwards it exists (with the 163 exit code, which is the number of the signal being sent).

This is not the behavior I want. I want that after receiving the signal, the script continues to wait for the processes (in this case the two functions) to terminate (which of course will not happen in this case, but the script should wait).

I tried it with adding a `; wait` to the things that should be done when receiving the signal, but this does not help (or I'm doing something wrong).

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired behavior?

Thanks in advance and with best wishes.

EDIT: Maybe a more precise example helps:

```sh
clock(){
        local prefix=C
        local interval=1
        while true
        do
                printf "${prefix} $(date '+%d.%m %H:%M:%S')\n"
                sleep $interval
        done
}

volume(){
        prefix=V
                volstat="$(amixer get Master 2>/dev/null)"

                echo "$volstat" | grep "\[off\]" >/dev/null && icon="" #alternative: deaf:  mute: 

                vol=$(echo "$volstat" | grep -o "\[[0-9]\+%\]" | sed "s/[^0-9]*//g;1q")

                if [ -z "$icon" ] ; then
                if [ "$vol" -gt "50" ]; then
                        icon=""
                #elif [ "$vol" -gt "30" ]; then
                #       icon=""
                else
                        icon=""
                fi
                fi

                printf "${prefix}%s %3s%%\n" "$icon" "$vol"
}

clock &
volume &

trap -- "volume" RTMIN+2

wait
```

Now the `RTMIN+2` signal should rerun the `volume` function, but the `clock` process should not be interrupted. (Up to now, the whole script (with all subprocesses) is terminated upon the receiving of the signal)

Comment: Try to replace `wait` by `while :;do wait;echo "V: " $vol;done`

Comment: Is this the same idea, you formulated in your answer?

Comment: Yes: `wait` will terminate when some signal are recieved. So you have to loop over. The `echo "V:  " $vol` could help you to see moment of execution.

Comment: Did you send `RTMIN+2` or `RTMIN+1`?

Comment: I sent `RTMIN+2`

Comment: Note U could write: `grep -q '\[off\]' <<<"$volstat" && icon=...` instead of `echo "$volstat" | grep "\[off\]" >/dev/null && icon=...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Something *rewritted*

In order to avoid some useless forks.

```
clock(){  local prefix=C interval=2
    trap : RTMIN{,+{{,1}{1,2,3,4,5},6,7,8,9,10}}
    while :;do
        printf "%s: %(%d.%m %H:%M:%S)T\n" $prefix -1
        sleep $interval
    done
}

volume(){  local prefix=V vol=() field playback val foo
    while IFS=':[]' read field playback val foo;do
        [ "$playback" ] && [ -z "${playback//*Playback*}" ] && [ "$val" ] &&
            vol+=(${val%\%})
    done < <(amixer get Master)
    suffix='%%'
    if [ "$vol" = "off" ] ;then
        icon="" #alternative: deaf:  mute: 
        suffix=''
    elif (( vol > 50 )) ;then  icon=""
    elif (( vol > 30 )) ;then  icon=""
    else                       icon=""
    fi
    printf -v values "%3s$suffix " ${vol[@]}
    printf "%s%s %s\n" $prefix "$icon" "$values"
}

clock & volume &

trap volume RTMIN+2
trap : RTMIN{,+{{,1}{1,3,4,5},6,7,8,9,10,12}}
echo -e "To get status, run:\n  kill -RTMIN+2 $$"

while :;do wait ;done
```

Regarding my last comment about stereo bug, there is a volume function working for stereo, mono or even quadra:

```
volume(){
    local prefix=V vol=() field playback val foo
    local -i overallvol=0
    while IFS=':[]' read field playback val foo ;do
        [ "$playback" ] && [ -z "${playback//*Playback*}" ] && [ "$val" ] && {
            vol+=($val)
            val=${val%\%}
            overallvol+=${val//off/0}
        }
      done < <(
        amixer get Master
    )
    overallvol=$overallvol/${#vol[@]}
    if (( overallvol == 0 )) ;then
        icon=""
      elif (( overallvol > 50 )) ;then
        icon=""
      elif (( overallvol > 30 )) ;then
        icon=""
      else
        icon=""
    fi
    printf "%s%s %s\n" $prefix "$icon" "${vol[*]}"
}
```

or even:

```
volume(){
    local prefix=V vol=() field playback val foo icons=(⏻ ¼ ¼ ¼ ½ ½ ¾ ¾ ¾ ¾ ¾)
    local -i overallvol=0
    while IFS=':[]' read field playback val foo ;do
        [ "$playback" ] && [ -z "${playback//*Playback*}" ] && [ "$val" ] && {
            vol+=($val)
            val=${val%\%}
            overallvol+=${val//off/0}
        }
      done < <(
        amixer get Master
    )
    overallvol=$overallvol/${#vol[@]}
    printf "%s%s %s\n" $prefix "${icons[(9+overall)/10]}" "${vol[*]}"
```

## Some explanations

### Regarding useless forks in *`volume()`* function

I've posted there some ideas to improve the job, reducing resource eating and doing same job of choosing an **icon** as function of current volume set.

### About `while :;do wait;done` loop

As requested sample stand for an infinite loop in backgrounded sub function, the main script use same infinite loop.

But as question title stand for *wait afterwards for processes to terminate*, I have to agree with [oguz-ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/110298229?noredirect=1).

In fact, last line would better be written:

```
until wait;do :;done
```

For more information on how `wait` command work and good practice, please have a look on good [oguz-ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62358228/1765658)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this why this works and the previous not?

Comment: Well actually, when I test this, the clock terminates after the process received the signal (just like mine did)

Comment: You have to send signal to main pid, not to clock subprocess! What is your environment (OS, version)

Comment: You could avoid exiting of subprocess by adding `trap :` into `clock` subprocess. See my last edit.

Comment: This is a good idea. (I sent the signal to the main process when testing your old version) I have one question left, what do you mean by `in order to avoid some useless forks`?

Comment: I've dropped `echo ...| grep ...| sed ...`, replaced by pure bash loop. (Nota `sed 's/.*\[\(off\|[0-9]\+\)%\?\].*/\1/;ta;bb;:a;q;:b;d' <<<"$volstat"` will avoid `echo ...| grep ...|` .)

Comment: With some improvment: Using integer test when possible, printing *left* and *right* volume if stereo system, by preparing *`$values`* output as separated step. Bug: Only *left* output is tested in stereo system: *left=off right=100%* will fail (percent sign will be missing and icon will be wrong).

Comment: Ah, I understand, but the real trick with the signalling, was to add the "empty" trap right? (just to be close this post)

Comment: Yes, but not *"empty"*, this trap run `:`, which is an alias to `true`, a command that run nothing but return success.

Comment: Isn't `while :;do wait ;done` an infinite loop? That script won't exit after the background processes terminate

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, but as `clock` function use same infinite loop and the goal of this is to **not** terminate clock loop, we have to do same infinite loop in ***main*** script. Of course ***`SIGINT`*** will terminate all of this.

Comment: I'm sorry to wake this up, but I just looked at this again as I wanted to implement this. In understand, that this works, but I still fail to see why. The clock process will receive the same signal as the main process and run `:`. But what keeps that process running after that?

Answer (score 4):

When invoked with no operands, `wait` exits with either **0**; which means all process IDs known by the invoking shell have terminated, or **a value greater than 128**; which means a signal for which a trap has been set is received. So, looping until `wait` exits with `0` is enough to keep the script alive after receiving a signal. You may also check whether its exit status is less than 128 within the loop, but I don't think that's necessary.

However, if you're sending those signals using `pkill`, the jobs started at the background will receive them too since child processes inherit the process name from their parent but not the custom signal handlers, and `pkill` signals all processes whose names match. You need to handle that case as well.

A minimal, working example would be:

```
#! /bin/bash -
# ignore RTMIN+1 and RTMIN+2 temporarily
# to prevent pkill from killing jobs
trap '' RTMIN+1 RTMIN+2

# start jobs
sleep 20 && echo slept for 20 seconds &
sleep 30 && echo slept for 30 seconds &

# set traps
trap 'echo received rtmin+1' RTMIN+1
trap 'echo received rtmin+2' RTMIN+2

# wait for jobs to terminate
until wait; do
  echo still waiting
done
```

It's also worth to note that ignoring `RTMIN+1` and `RTMIN+2` before starting jobs prevents shells descending from them from trapping/reseting those signals. If that is a problem, you may set an *empty trap* within jobs as F. Hauri suggested; or you may totally drop ignoring and use `pkill` with `-o` option to send the signal to the oldest matching process.

References:

- [Shell Command Language § Signals and Error Handling](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11)
- [`wait` spec. § EXIT STATUS](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html#tag_20_153_14)

Related:

- [Reliably kill sleep process after USR1 signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201746/reliably-kill-sleep-process-after-usr1-signal)