# Trap Command not detecting terminal resize (SIGWINCH)

Tags: bash, bash-trap

Im trying to detect when my menu is resized using `trap "echo resized" SIGWINCH` but it doesnt seem to be detecting it. Im currently using ubuntu 20.04 and i am using a bash script to do this.
The trap command is at the top of my script. Why is it not executing?

Comment: try removing the `SIG` prefix as: `trap 'echo resized' WINCH`. Tested it working with `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`.

Comment: Question was voted down by someone who did not understand the question. Anyone able to answer the question can easily understand it. It is a good question.

Comment: Solution proposed by @Léa Gris worked for me also (Konsole on KDE Plasma, bash 5.1). Thus `WINCH` instead of `SIGWINCH` was required for the `trap` to catch the signal. If `read` is required instead of a loop, remember to set a timeout to the `read`, e.g. `read -t 0.5` (this works in most cases, see also https://github.com/dylanaraps/fff/issues/48#issuecomment-453808371).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to bash manual (`man bash`):

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, **the trap will not be executed until the command completes.**

You can verify this with:

```
trap 'echo resized' SIGWINCH

while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694818/interrupt-sleep-in-bash-with-a-signal-trap