# Shell session exited by itself after issuing command "exec<>5"

Tags: shell, unix, exec, defects

When issued two commands below in Linux or MacOS, the Shell session exited and no any error message displayed.

```
➜  ~  sh
sh-3.2$ exec<>5
sh-3.2$ exit    ==> 'exit' was issued by the shell itself!
```

Is this a defect of '/bin/sh'? Can anyone provide any insight?

/bin/sh on my RHEL:

> -sh-4.1$ sh --version
>   GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
>   Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

/bin/sh on my MacOS:

> ➜  ~  sh --version
>   GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
>   Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: What we have above it's called "diamond operator" and it's usually used to redirect both stdin and stdout to another file descriptor: exec 5<>file. In your example you don't have the file descriptor, only the file (named 5 on this example). But why it exits, I have no idea.

Comment: Check this explanation: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/ at "11. Open a file both for writing and reading"

Comment: you are right, 5 at here is a file, but I don't think sh should exit after hitting such a tiny error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default file descriptor before a "<" is stdin, so read your command as `exec 0<>5`.  That is, replace stdin with read/write from/to a file named "5".  Since the file is empty, the shell exits (no more input.)  If you actually put shell commands in the file you can see this happen.  Try this:

```
echo 'echo here i am; sleep 3' >5
exec <>5
```

Comment: Right answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to a command line such as Linux or Unix, exec is a BOURNE and POSIX shell command that replaces the current shell process with the command specified after exec. This command does not create a new PID. For example, if you were to run `exec <command>`, the shell would be replaced by that command. When that command is exited, the shell will exit.
You can also have a look at these links.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdln_exec.htm

[What are the uses of the exec command in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: In my case, I didn't replace the shell process, just redirect its stdin/stdout to another file descriptor.