# What happens when I sudo bash -c?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sudo

I know that `sudo bash -c 'some_command'` will run `some_command` with the same privileges as sudo.

I'm confused as to what's happening? Does it run `some_command` in bash as sudo (same as `sudo bash`) then switch back to my current user? Why am I not left in an instance of bash with sudo privileges like I would when I run `sudo bash`?

I tried running `man bash` and it describes the `-c` option (quoted below). 
However, I am struggling to piece how the description relates to the behaviour I observed when running `sudo bash -c 'some_command'`

> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there  are  arguments  after
>                    the command_string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` switches users and then executes `bash`, passing it the other arguments. `bash` running as the new user runs the command in the argument after `-c`.

Comment: Does it then exit bash automatically after the command after `-c` is executed? How come the behaviour is different to running `sudo bash` and then specifying the command after `bash`

Comment: Because that's how bash works. If you don't specify a command then it opens a REPL.

Comment: Mind if I modify your answer to add that to it? That last part pretty much answers my question

Answer (score 5):

Consider this snippet (pay attention to UID & PID/PPID columns.):

```
$ sudo ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      8997  8715  0 11:57 pts/17   00:00:00 sudo ps -f
root      8998  8997  0 11:57 pts/17   00:00:00 ps -f

$ sudo bash -c 'ps -f'
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      8909  8715  3 11:55 pts/17   00:00:00 sudo bash -c ps -f
root      8910  8909  0 11:55 pts/17   00:00:00 ps -f

$ sudo bash -c 'echo hi; ps -f'
hi
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      8957  8715  0 11:56 pts/17   00:00:00 sudo bash -c echo hi; ps -f
root      8958  8957  0 11:56 pts/17   00:00:00 bash -c echo hi; ps -f
root      8959  8958  0 11:56 pts/17   00:00:00 ps -f
```

1. In 1st case, `sudo` starts `ps -f` as `root` user.
2. In 2nd case, `sudo` starts `bash` as `root` user with arguments `-c 'ps -f'`. It appears that as an optimization, `bash` is using `exec` to start `ps -f`. Hence, only 2 processes are seen.
3. In 3rd case, `sudo` starts `bash` as `root` user with arguments `-c 'echo hi; ps -f'`. The command (argument to `-c`) is not a simple executable + args. They are 2 commands separated by `;`. So, `bash` cannot call `exec` directly. It uses the standard `fork+exec` mechanism. So, `bash` is the parent of the `ps` process.

Comment: Good one.  Linked here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts/38581329#comment64551906_38581329