# cannot understand combined exec and redirection in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I know exec is for executing a program in current process as quoted down from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts)

> exec replaces the current program in the current process, without
>   forking a new process. It is not something you would use in every
>   script you write, but it comes in handy on occasion.

I'm looking at a bash script a line of which I can't understand exactly.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG="log.txt"
exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG")
echo Logging output to "$LOG"
```

Here, exec doesn't have any program name to run. what does it mean? and it seems to be capturing the execution output to a log file. I would understand if it was `exec program |& tee log.txt` but here, I cannot understand `exec &> >(tee -a log.txt)`. why another `>` after `&>`?
What's the meaning of the line? (I know -a option is for appending and `&>` is for redirecting including stderr)

EDIT : after I selected the solution, I found the `exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG")` works when it is bash shell(not sh). So I modified the initial `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`. But `exec &>> "$LOG"` works both for bash and sh.

Comment: Does your system have the bash manual page installed? Start it and search for "exec " (exec followed by a space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
>
> If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the
>   current shell, [...]

And the rest:

```
&>     # redirects stdout and stderr
>(cmd) # redirects to a process
```

See [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: Could you explain in the context of the example?

Comment: You're redirecting the output of the current shell.

Comment: Thankyou. Nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you, so in other words, exec &> redirects the output of the current shell script, and the following > redirects it to the log file. (Wow, this means I can redirect the script's output to a file inside the script!).

Comment: I changed `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` because `exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG")` works only when it is bash.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some  details to:

```
exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG")
```

here we see two **">"** but they mean quite different things.
the first one

```
"&>"
```

is related with "bash io redirection".
the second one

```
">(tee -a "$LOG")"
```

has nothing to do with it. it is related with  "bash Process Substitution"

The redirection **"&>"** requires the filename is specified in the next argument. And indeed the filename of redirection is supplyed via **">(tee -a "$LOG")"** by bash process substitution.
I'm not sure what bash substitutes in case of "exec built-in" however strace clearly shows usage of /dev/fd/63 file

```
$ echo $$
10516
$ exec &> >(tee -a 7.txt)
# strace -p 10516 -f  -s80  -e openat
[pid 10516] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/fd/63", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
```

At least when we use external commands(not bash built-ins) - bash substitutes **/dev/fd/63** as the filename. like in this example:

```
$ cp /dev/urandom >(pv 1>/dev/null)
# ps aux | grep "cp /dev/urandom"
      ... cp /dev/urandom /dev/fd/63
```

you can  see  ">(pv 1>/dev/null)" is replaced to "/dev/fd/63" by bash,
also /dev/fd is a symlink to /proc/self,  and 63 is a symlink to a pipe 'pipe:[2492389]',
so

/dev/fd/63 --> /proc/self/fd/63 ---> 'pipe:[2492389]'

As the final result in the initial bash process stdout and stderr will be redirected to the pipe like this:

```
 /proc/$bash_pid/fd/1 ---> 'pipe:[2492389]'  
 /proc/$bash_pid/fd/2 ---> 'pipe:[2492389]'
```

Next,
bash creates a new process and launches "tee" in there.
stdin of "tee" process will be bind to  the pipe

```
/proc/$tee_pid/fd/0 ---> 'pipe:[2492389]'
```

Finally we have a chain:

```
bash STDOUT,STDERR ----> pipe ----> STDIN tee
```