# How can exec() be used with command line input?

Tags: c, process, exec, parent-child, command-line-arguments

Can someone please explain the use of exec functions when the input is given in command line? For example, if entered:

```
$ ./a.out ls -l
```

where a.out is the executable file. It would be great if you could share examples so that I can get clarification.

P.S. I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts) thread, but I need clarification with command line inputs primarily.

Comment: Have you read about [the `exec` family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)? Do you know how to use the? Consider how you pass the arguments to e.g. `execvp`, and compare it to how your `main` function receives its arguments. Notice any similarities with the `execvp` arguments and the `main` function `argv` argument?

Comment: Oh by the way, you *are* aware of that allowing something like this could be a security hole big enough for an oil-tanker?

Comment: I have already been trying. However, I am not yet comfortable enough to answer anything related to exec functions, and thus, looking for help. I am not aware if it leaves a big hole, although that doesn't stops me from exploring it. It does make me more curios though. I can somehow use it (not the entire family) when I know the inputs.  It might be helpful if you could share some examples or maybe a link as reference @Someprogrammerdude