# Understanding exec in bash

Tags: linux, bash, exec, io-redirection, process-substitution

After reading [explanations of how the exec builtin works in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts), I understand that its basic function is to replace the current process without forking.  It also seems to be used for redirecting I/O and closing file descriptors in the current process, which confuses me.  Is this some unrelated additional thing `exec` does?  Can it be understood in the context of "replacing the current process"?  And how does this work when combined with process substitution, e.g. `exec 3< <(my program)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what `exec` does:

1. Set up all redirections in the current process.

   - This is a combination of `open`, `dup2` and `close` syscalls for most operations like `> foo`
   - `pipe` + `fork` + `/dev/fd/*` is used for process substition
   - Temporary files are created and opened for here-documents and here-strings
2. Replace the process image (using `execve`) with the specified program, **if any**

If you don't specify a program to run, step 2 is simply skipped, and all redirections therefore affect the rest of the script.

`<(Process substitution)` works by `pipe`+`fork`+`/dev/fd/`:

1. Create a pipe as normal.
2. Copy it to FD 63 or somewhere it won't be in the way
3. Fork and run a program that reads/writes to the pipe.
4. Replace the process substitution with `/dev/fd/63`, a special file that will return FD 63 when opened. (try `echo <(ls)`).

From then on, it works just like redirecting from any other file. You open `/dev/fd/63` for reading on FD 3, and then you end up reading from the pipe. `exec` therefore doesn't need to do anything special.

Comment: @Kvass: If you are interested in the way process substitution works under the covers, the source code file is `subst.c` and the function is `process_substitute`, there are quite a few comments.  Line 5049 here: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/bash/subst.c