# Curl command not working in load.sh in dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have docker file:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

COPY build/libs/codes-converter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /tmp
COPY mappings.yaml /

ADD load.sh /

RUN chmod +x /load.sh

CMD ["/load.sh"]
```

load.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n -jar tmp/codes-converter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

sleep 10

curl http://localhost:8090/codes-converter/load-mappings
```

So basically, i need to connect to one of my endpoints of my java app inside the container after the container startup. But I can't figure out how to do it. Where are my mistakes? This curl command seems not working.

Comment: you are stuck in `exec java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n -jar tmp/codes-converter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` , you ned to add `&`  at end of the command

Comment: `exec` replaces current shell with given command. Just use: `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n -jar tmp/codes-converter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Even remove exec & put it to background could not help I guess, container need this command `java xxx` to be run in foreground to avoid it exit. You need separate `curl` to other parts not in this container, consider modify your design.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is running some kind of data migration after container is launched. I would suggest running it outside of API context as a script of some sort, and only then launching the API after migration is finished.

If yet you insist of running it this way, I can see two different ways of doing it:

1. Daemonize the `time.sleep` and `curl` before the server is launched (i.e making it run in the background, waiting until the server is up)
2. Create a single cronjob that will be executed in parallel to the server process