# Using exec in a makefile

Tags: python, makefile, exec

In a makefile, what is the difference between

```
python:
    exec python
```

and

```
python:
    python
```

I found it [here](https://github.com/sio/Makefile.venv/blob/master/Makefile.venv#L156). I understand that `exec` replaces the shell with the command being executed, in this case python. But I don't really see the implications in a makefile.

So **why** would i use `exec python` rather than `python`?

Comment: I don't know.  Why would you?  There's no point to it that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` command is useful for specific cases when writing scripts. One such example is when we want an application to run without access to a shell process after execution. You can read more about those use cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts).

For the situation you gave, there is no practical difference between `exec python` and `python`, other than not being able to return to your shell after python is finished executing with the `exec` command. You're better off just using `python`.