# Running a command with bash -c vs without

Tags: bash

What is the difference between these two commands?

1. `cat test.txt`
2. `bash -c "cat test.txt"`

I already read the documentation but there was not any example to understand it.

Comment: This is by and large also applicable to questions about `sh -c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat test.txt` in the shell tells it to execute the command `cat` with the argument `test.txt`

`bash -c "cat text.txt"` tells it to execute the command `bash` with the arguments `-c` and `cat test.txt`. The latter obviously ends up repeating what was stated above once the new shell instance has been loaded.

(I believe Bash has some internal optimizations to somewhat simplify what *actually* happens when you ask it to run a second copy of itself, but I guess that's beside the point here really.)

There are situations where you need to specify a single command for some reason (maybe a hook in another program lets you run a command, but only one) and you need to run more than one command; or when you want to use shell features like redirection or wildcard expansion in a separate shell instance.

```
sudo bash -c "whoami; test [ -w / ] && echo 'Fun to be privileged!'"
sudo bash -c 'echo 1 >/proc/privileged/something'  # though see also "sudo tee"
find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/.txt/.csv}"' _ {} \;
```

The final example uses the Bash-only parameter expansion `${variable/pattern/replacement}` to change `.txt` to `.csv`; neither `find` nor `mv` has any facility for doing this sort of replacement, so calling a shell to do it is easy and convenient (though maybe first check if you have a `rename` command which would be able to do it in a single simple command like `rename '/\.txt$/.csv/' **/*.txt`)

Also, if you are running another shell, but want to use Bash for something (there are many Bash-only features which are handy; see also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)), this is a way to do that; though if you are doing this in a script, obviously then it would usually make more sense to write the entire script in Bash.

In isolation, just running `cat test.txt` in a subshell is merely wasteful, and costs you an extra process for no actual benefit.

Perhaps tangentially note also that the double quotes cause the calling shell to perform variable substitutions in the quoted string before passing it as an argument to the executable. Single quotes are probably better if you don't specifically require this behavior.

Notice also that

```
bash -c ./script foo bar baz
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
./script foo bar baz
```

In fact, the former puts `foo` in `"$0"`! The general convention if you want to pass in arguments with `bash -c` is to put `_` or `bash` in the first argument.

```
bash -c ./script bash foo bar baz
```

Another convention to be aware of is that `login` puts a dash in front when the shell is interactive, so that you can check whether you are running an interactive shell simply by checking whether `$0` starts with `-`.

Comment: When you need a shell for some reason, for example because you are in a place where you are allowed to run exactly one shell command (but not prevented from running another shell as that command) or because you need shell features like redirection or wildcard expansion for something running in a subprocess (like with `sudo`). Perhaps see also my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts though the scope there is obviously different.

Comment: Updated now with a discussion

Comment: When you're not in bash but some other shell, but you want to run bash code you'd also use that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Good point; adding that.