# The difference between "sudo sh -c" and "su -c"

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want to start a program as root when booting, and will add one of the following lines to rc.local:

```
sudo /path/my_prog
sudo sh -c "/path/my_prog"
su -c "/path/my_prog"
```

What is the difference between this three lines, and which is the correct one?

Comment: What is the difference between `grep '^' file` and `cat file`? :-)

Comment: Perhaps see also [Running a command with `bash -c` vs without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769529/running-a-command-with-bash-c-vs-without) (where obviously the question is about Bash, not `sh`; but parts of the question clearly apply to `sh -c command` vs `command` just as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any of them; `rc.local` runs with `root` privileges.  The correct answer is to simply run your command.

```
/path/my_prog
```

`su` makes sense if you are `root` and want to switch to a different account.

`sudo` makes sense if you are running on an unprivileged account, and have been granted the rights to switch to another account (often, but not always, `root`), usually with the requirement to be able to interactively supply your password (though this can be turned off if you really have to; obviously, you need to understand what you are doing before you mess with security-related stuff).

`sh -c "command"` is just an inefficient way to run `command`. Running a shell makes sense when you actually require shell features such as wildcard expansion, redirection, etc, or shell builtins like `cd`.

Ideally, you might want to make sure that `my_prog` runs on a dedicated unprivileged system account; then, the syntax would be

```
su otheraccount -c /path/my_prog
```

where obviously you need to create `otheraccount` and make sure it has the privileges that are required for performing this particular task.

`su` optionally lets you add a lone dash before the account name to have it run a login session; but for a service account, this probably does not make sense.

Comment: To run as another user I have seen ```su - otheraccount -c /path/my_prog```. What is the difference between this and ```su otheraccount -c /path/my_prog```?

Comment: As `man su` will readily reveal, the lone dash instructs it to run a login session. Updated the answer with a sentence about this.

Answer (score 1):

- `sudo /path/my_prog` will execute `/path/my_prog` with sudo privileges.
- `sudo sh -c "/path/my_prog"` will execute `/path/my_prog` (specified by the flag `-c`) with **sh** using sudo privileges.
- `su -c "/path/my_prog"` will execute `/path/my_prog` (specified by the flag `-c`) with your current shell using sudo privileges.

The *correct one* to use depends on your use case, so actually it's up to you. IMHO, `sudo foo` and `su -c foo` are basically the same.

Comment: No, they are not at all the same. `su` requires you to have the root password; the whole purpose of `sudo` is to enable the admin to _selectively_ grant privileges to users _without_ sharing the root password.