# Error with array and sed WP config replacement

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find, sh

```
newwpuser=$cpuser"_"$wpuser
newwpdb=$cpuser"_"$wpdb
wpdb=($(find . -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -e "DB_NAME" | cut -d \' -f 4))
wpuser=($(find . -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -e "DB_USER" | cut -d \' -f 4))
wpconfigchanges=($(find . -name wp-config.php -type f))

for i in "${wpconfigchanges[@]}"; do -exec sed -i -e "/DB_USER/s/'$wpuser'/'$newwpuser'/" | -exec sed -i -e "/DB_NAME/s/'$wpdb'/'$newwpuser'/"; done
```

I am trying to run the above in order to find all Wordpress configs and prepend the dbuser and dbname with cpuser_

However, I get the following error;

```
./test.sh: line 85: -exec: command not found
./test.sh: line 85: -exec: command not found
```

Have I input the exec commands wrong?

`cpuser` is input on execution.

Comment: Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `-exec` is not the name of a valid command. It is unclear why you thought it was, or what you hoped it would do.

Most probably you were simply trying to say ... the same thing without `-exec`, and without the crazy `sed` pipe;

```
for i in "${wpconfigchanges[@]}"; do
    sed -i -e "/DB_USER/s/'$wpuser'/'$newwpuser'/" \
           -e "/DB_NAME/s/'$wpdb'/'$newwpuser'/" "$i"
done
```

In very brief, the pipeline `a | b` runs the commands `a` and `b` in such a way that the output from `a` is the input to `b`; but if `a` is `sed -i`, it does not produce any output (it writes it back to its input file); and if `b` is `sed -i`, it does not read its standard input (it reads it from the file argument you provide on its command line; though you also forgot to use `"$i"` for anything inside the loop).

What you want could be expressed as two separate `sed -i` commands (with just a newline or semicolon between them, not a pipe `|`); but repeatedly running `sed -i` on the same file is repetitive, inelegant, and inefficient: You open the file, copy all the lines to a temporary file, with a small change on one line, then rename the temporary file - only to then do the same thing again with another temporary file. And anyway, `sed` is a scripting language, albeit a primitive one; it was specifically designed to perform multiple commands in one go.

You probably got `-exec` from an example with `find`, something like

```bash
find . -type f \
    -name '*.sh' \
    -exec sed -i '1s%^!#/bin/bash%#!/bin/sh%' {} \;
```

... but here, `-exec` (and `-type`, and `-name`) are options to control what the `find` command should do; we are telling it to search the current directory (`.`) and its subdirectories for regular files (as in, not directories, symbolic links, device files, etc; `-type f`) matching a particular naming pattern (`-name '*.sh'`); and to execute (`-exec ... \;`) a particular command sequence on the found files (here, `sed -i '1s%^!#/bin/bash%#!/bin/sh%'`; the `{}` placeholder indicates where to add the file name on the command line; and `\;` terminates the entire string of arguments to `-exec`).

... But in fact, it would be better to just do that. Notice that you don't really know or care what is being replaced; so running `find` twice to find the original values is basically redundant, as well as brittle (what if different `wp-config.php` files have different values? Then `find` would return a sequence of multiple strings, which probably don't occur concatenated in your files at all - and even if they did, `sed` cannot handle a newline in the middle of the `s/.../.../` command). Instead, let's just replace the fourth field on those lines.

Also, collecting the output of the last `find` into an array is brittle (the array will not correctly capture file names which contain whitespace) as well as a waste of memory (capturing the file names in a variable so you can then simply loop over them and then immediately discard them is entirely useless, when `find` itself already provides a way).

`find` can also be a very expensive command; if the directory tree isn't guaranteed to be absolutely tiny, you really want to avoid traversing it more than once.

```
find . -name wp-config.php \
    -type f -exec sed -i -E \
      -e "/DB_NAME/s/^(([^']*'){3})/\1${cpuser}_/" \
      -e "/DB_USER/s/^(([^']*'){3})/\1${cpuser}_/" {} +
```

The `-E` option to `sed` (which is nonstandard, but almost certainly available if you also have `-i`) selects a slightly more modern and versatile regular expression dialect; concretely, it removes the eyesore of backslashes before the parentheses in the capturing expression and the braces. The notation `{3}` says to repeat the previous regular expression three times, and `[^']*'` matches text up through the next single quote (so, zero or more characters which are not a single quote, followed by a single quote). The text matched by the parentheses is available in `\1`; so, we replace the first three single-quoted fields with themselves, followed by the new prefix.

(I am assuming that assigning `newwpuser` before having the correct value for `wpuser` was another bug in your attempt, and similarly for `newwpdb`; if not, it's not hard to put that back. In fact, a version of this answer from before Christmas 2023 had this implementation, until I realized it was probably another bug.)

As an aside, replacing text by itself might seem mysterious, until you realize that phrasing the search in this way allows us to precisely target a specific field for replacement. In other words, this can be generalized to *s/(anchoring prefix)find this(anchoring suffix)/\1replacement\2/*

This answer is long and meandering because your script had many complications. Going forward, it's much better to reduce your problem to a [minimum reproducible example](/help/mcve) with a single problem where the code doesn't do exactly what you want (but then each of these questions would be a relatively common beginner problem which has already been answered many times; please search before asking).

You are also unlucky that `find` and `sed` are some of the murkier corners of the shell ecosystem. Part of the challenge is that these commands are poorly standardized, though I have basically assumed you are on a GNU/Linux system (the `sed -i` syntax would be different on MacOS, for example).

Comment: Finding the strings to search for so that you can then search and replace them is basically a variation on [Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538947/counting-lines-or-enumerating-line-numbers-so-i-can-loop-over-them-why-is-this)